# Problem with adding contextual link with option in yml file

Tags: navigation, 8

In a custom module, I want to add a contextual link for all nodes, using the *mymodule.links.contextual.yml* file.

It works well with a route without options:

```
mymodule.test:
  route_name: entity.node.edit_form
  group: node
  title: Test
```

but I can't make it work with:

```
mymodule.test2:
  route_name: node.add:article
  group: node
  title: Test2
```

I tried a lot of different possibilities without success. Does anyone has an idea of what could be missing?

Comment: add route_parameters: { ARGUMENT_NAME: node }

Comment: I tried with route_parameters: { node_type: article } but the link still doesn't appear, and no php error is logged